# Не получается установить соединение по локальной сети

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, сокет

Пытаюсь подключиться к серверу на распбери пи по локлаьной сети. Узнал локальный адрес сети - 127.0.0.1. Бинд на распбери пи проходит нормально, но при попытке коннекта с ноутбука на распбери выдает вот такую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anton/Programming/project_python3/client_2.py", line 12, in <module>
    clientsocket.connect((HOST, PORT))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

И ноутбук и распбери подключены к одной wifi сети и коннект происходит по одному и тому же порту. В моем проекте мне важно использовать для локальной сети wifi телефона, когда я делал тоже самое с домашнего wifi все было нормально, там был другой адресс

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - это не "локальный адрес сети", это loopback адрес - под этим адресом любое устройство видит само себя. Т.е. у вас ноутбук пытается подключиться к самому себе. Адрес raspberry нужно или узнать с него самого с помощью команды ifconfig в терминале, или с другого устройство сканером ip адресов.

Comment: @insolor, а что именно нужно посмотреть в ifconfig?

Comment: Смотрите параметр inet. Пример: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjXdp.png Ну и на raspberry вроде бы нужно биндиться не к 127.0.0.1, а к 0.0.0.0 (или к фактическому ip адресу, к тому что в ifconfig увидите), иначе все равно не будет доступно снаружи.